# why SpringTemplateEngine in thymeleaf don`t process my template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i want send email with spring framework and thymeleaf .but when i run to the `process`, it doesn`t continue to run.

my Configuration:

```
<bean id="emailResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/template/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"></property>
    <property name="order" value="1"></property>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="emailResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

java snippets:

```
    @Autowired
    SpringTemplateEngine                            templateEngine;
    public void createThyTest()
    {
        Context con = new Context();
        con.setVariable("name", "volcanno");
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(""));
        String string2 = templateEngine.process("Test.html", con);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println(string2);
    }
```

when i run the code，there is no any "---" to be output.

output:

```
file:/D:/Neon_eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ProjectDemo/WEB-INF/classes/
```

No other error message is output.
and i use :

```
thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring 3.1.2
```

thanks

my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <p th:text="#{greeting(${name})}">
      Hello, Peter Static!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and i change the <code>prefix</code>  value to <code>template/</code>,the output still has not changed.

Comment: In your Java snippet, change "Test.html" to just "Test" if that is the name of your file

Comment: i try it,but still faile.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions?  Also, try to to make the template simpler to see what's broken.  Use `<p th:text="${name}">` and see whether that prints.  And autowire `TemplateEngine` from Thymeleaf, not `SpringTemplateEngine`

Comment: (The autowire change won't fix the problem, it's just cleaner)

Comment: in fact ,i am always confusing that where to put the "Test.html".